# Python define a class method in another Python .py file

Tags: python

Due to means of visualization, I would like to define the methods that I wrote for a class outside of the class - specifically, in another .py file. At least this is how our teacher at university taught us to organize a code

Can someone please tell me how I would be able to define and then later on call the function output_func() in another file?

I know that it was possible in C++ by typing classname::functionname(Parameter) and then declaring it in the class, but I don't know the way in Python.

I am sure that this is a very common and basic question; nevertheless, I could not find any solution to it with my personal research. That being said, sorry if I have just asked a duplicate question :)

Thank you very much!

The example code:

```
class MainClass():
    
    #The method that I would like to define in another file 
    def output_func():

        print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: you can use it this way `x = MainClass() \n x.output_func()`

Comment: You may have been taught to organize your code that way *in C++*, but that's because of technical details specific to C++. It's not a good idea across languages.

Comment: you should decorate this method with a `@staticmethod` (there is no `self` as first argument). then call it as `MainClass.output_func()`. if you put it in a module or package, you'd have to `import` the class accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to want to call `output_func`. If you want it to be a static class method, you can define it like this:

```py
@staticmethod
def output_func():
    print("hello world")

from ModuleWithMainClass import MainClass
MainClass.output_func = output_func

# call like this
MainClass.output_func()
```

If you want `output_func` to act like a regular instance method and have internal access to the object you can define it like this:

```py
def output_func(self):
    print(f"hello {self._name}")

from ModuleWithMainClass import MainClass
MainClass.output_func = output_func

# call like this
mc = MainClass()
mc.output_func()
```

Splitting class definitions across multiple files is quite un-pythonic. I would reconsider if this is the best solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have thought about doing so because I have a class with multiple methods that simply take up a lot of space. But if you say that it is common to organize all of the same code in one file in Python, I will leave it that way - it works in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@staticmethod
def output_function():
    return "Hello World."

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

MainClass.output_function = output_function

mcl = MainClass()
print(mcl.output_function())
# Hello World.
```

Comment: `output_func` still needs to be declared with `@staticmethod`, otherwise yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use classes or functions from a different file, you have to import them (typically at the beginning of the current file, but defineately before you use them. have you tried `import file` and then using `file.yourfunction` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Nevertheless, this is sadly not exactly what I was asking for haha.